# SQL Server Express 2008 R2 - bootstrapper package

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, deployment, clickonce

So, Micosoft has basically given a big middle finger for those wanting to deploy SQL Server Express 2008 R2 as can be seen [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/560030/sql-server-express-2008-r2-bootstrapper-package) Does anyone know of a reasonable workaround for this? I need the bootstrapper for a ClickOnce app I'm deploying.

Comment: Require an install separately? It's quite irritating in a large corporate shop to have unpatched SQL Server installs in the wild because some vendor bundled it.

Comment: Well I'm part of a "large corporate shop". It's an internal app. It's just not feasible to make our users install it separately.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Comment: Wow, saying thanks is a tagline? Okay..

Comment: @Cody No, but signing your name is a signature. Just think of Stack Overflow as a reference, not a forum, and write your posts accordingly.

Comment: Seems as though this bootstrapper still isn't included in VS 2010 SP1 beta which just came out. According to MS that is when they release new bootstrappers; when VS is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the lovely RobinDotNet has heard our cry and helped us out by creating a bootstrapper for us.
[Here's](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/how-about-a-bootstrapper-package-for-sqlserver-express-2008-r2/) her blog post on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, Cody C! I'm glad I was able to figure it out, with some help from the SQLExpress program manager at MSFT. I'm as vexed as everyone else, and expressed that repeatedly to MSFT.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own bootstrapper with dotNetInstaller.

dotNetInstaller: http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/

Quick overview of how to use it: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotNetInstaller.aspx

Just add an exe component. I would pick the SQL Server 2008 R2 full download executable:
http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes without a comment. Notice that I posted 3 months before the accepted solution and before the blog post came out. Then all of a sudden people downvote this answer. Ridiculous.